# How to use entity_metadata_wrapper in hook_boot

Tags: entities, hooks

I am trying to create an entity with entity_metadata_wrapper from within hook_boot.  I know everyone will say "use hook_init" but for performance reasons, I'm going w/ hook_boot :) .

I have a couple modules loaded like so:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';
drupal_load('module', 'entity');
drupal_load('module', 'field');
```

This is what I have:

```
$entity = entity_create('myentity', array('type' => 'click'));
$ew = entity_metadata_wrapper('myentity',$entity);
$ew->field_myentity_url_reference->set($row->rid);
$ew->save();
```

The above works fine if run normally (like from form_alter or something), but not from hook_boot.

I am getting the following errors:

```
Warning: class_implements(): object or string expected in entity_create() (line 367 of /data/disk/host/distro/005/drupal-7.18.1-dev/sites/mysite.com/modules/entity/entity.module).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in entity_create() (line 367 of /data/disk/host/distro/005/drupal-7.18.1-dev/sites/mysite.com/modules/entity/entity.module).
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /data/disk/host/distro/005/drupal-7.18.1-dev/sites/mysite.com/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

Anyone know what else I need to drupal_load to get this to work?

### **EDIT - Figure out how to do this:**

I used the background process module: http://drupal.org/project/background_process.  I added the code below to hook_boot:

```
//load the required modules needed to do background_process
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/path.inc';
drupal_load('module', 'background_process');
drupal_load('module', 'progress');

background_process_start('shurly_create_click_log', $row);//  drupal_load('module', 'entity');
```

Then I put the entity code in a new function:

```
function shurly_create_click_log ($row){
    $entity = entity_create('linkpin', array('type' => 'click'));
    $ew = entity_metadata_wrapper('linkpin',$entity);
    $ew->field_linkpin_url_reference->set($row->rid);
    $ew->save();
}
```

Basically, the shurly_create_click_log function gets ran at full bootstrap in the background, so it doesn't slow down my pageload/redirect from hook_boot.

Comment: I figured out how to do this... not by calling it directly though.  See my edit above.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer, and accept it.  That's totally acceptable in Stack Exchange land, and will stop your question from showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a solution.

Add this to the top of your hook_boot() function:

```
function hook_boot() {
  global $user, $base_path;
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
...
}
```

drupal_bootstrap keeps track of what level it has been called so this trick effectively pushes hook_boot to being later in the boot process.

Comment: There's no reason to do this, ever. You're breaking the whole point of hook_boot() by doing this, which is specifically to **not** perform a full bootstrap, and your cached page performance will degrade for no reason. This is what hook_init() is for.